# Messy and repetitive output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My code is functionally correct. The problem is that the output isn't the way it should be. Things should be spaced correctly and for some reason I get a duplicate file name when I use the $line variable.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
 printf "Enter a directory path."
 read path
 if [ -e $path ]
    then
            echo -e "Filename \t Lines \t \t Type"
            echo -e "--------- \t ------ \t -----"
            for f in `$path/ls`
                    do
                            if [ -f $f ]
                                    then
                                    lines=`wc -l $f`
                                    echo -e " $f \t $lines \t \t Regular File "

                            else
                                    echo -e " $f \t N/A \t \t Directory File "



                            fi
                    done
    else
            printf "Directory path does not exist"
fi
```

Output looks like this:

```
Filename         Lines           Type 
---------        ------          -----
Desktop         N/A             Directory File
Documents       N/A             Directory File
Downloads       N/A             Directory File
Music   N/A             Directory File
mycrontab       0 mycrontab             Regular File
mycrontab.txt   1 mycrontab.txt                 Regular File
wc: mynewfile.txt: Permission denied
mynewfile.txt                   Regular File
myscript        26 myscript             Regular File
myscript.sh     24 myscript.sh                  Regular File
mytextlog.txt   91 mytextlog.txt                Regular File
Pictures        N/A             Directory File
Public          N/A             Directory File
Templates       N/A             Directory File
typescript      0 typescript            Regular File
Videos          N/A             Directory File
yumassignment.txt       1784 yumassignment.txt                  Regular File
```

Comment: `wc -l $f` will also return the filename itself, not just the number of lines. Use awk: `wc -l $f |awk '{print $1;}'`. And I don't think a single set of tabs will ensure proper positioning of your columns, if the entries vary too much in length. You might want to use `printf %10s` and similar structures to force columnwise ordering, but there might also be a more suitable solution to this part of your question.

Comment: Even better: `wc -l < "$f"` -- send the data on stdin and no filename is printed at all.

Comment: Is "pretty" a project requirement? I would write this output to a tab delimited file, then run a script to space it out as desired or open it in a spreadsheet tool.

Comment: What andras said is a pretty good solution.  If you are interested in more complex formatting in console, check out dialog ( http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html ) and simplecurses ( https://github.com/metal3d/bashsimplecurses )

Comment: Yes pretty is a requirement. I figured there were better ways to format but since im in an introductory class I figured it wouldn't be the best idea. Regardless, I don't see why, for example the N/A part of the music file would be displayed so closely to the file name when im formatting in a loop.

Comment: For pretty, pipe the output into `| column -t`

Comment: "I don't see why ..." -- tab stops at 8 characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key

Comment: @glennjackman, I though about that as well. But doesn't `column` mess up your columns if some of your fields contain spaces?

Comment: "I went to my programmer, and he said *<<You've got messy and repetitive output>>*. So I turned to him and said, *<<You think that's bad, you should hear my ex-wife!>>*" -- [Rodney Dangerfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_Dangerfield)

Comment: @AndrasDeak, yes the default column separator is "whitespace", but if you know the delimiter is something like a tab, you can use `column -s`

Comment: @glennjackman, perfect, thanks. Something like this was what I was hoping for when I said "there might also be a more suitable solution".

Answer (score 1):

You have your answer up in the comments. Some code review:

- your indentation style is ... interesting.
- use `read -p "prompt" path`, you don't to print the prompt separately
- always quote variables, especially if the value comes from the user: `if [ -e "$path" ]`
- [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `for f in "$path"/*`
- as mentioned: `lines=$(wc -l < $"f")`

Comment: My indentation doesn't actually look exactly like that. Some of that is copy and past errors.